# Adding a third axis to a scatter plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I just have a question about how to add a third axis(a secondary x axis) to a existing scatter plot. 
For example, I have the following dataframe:

```
df = data.frame(a = c(10,20,30,40,50,60,70),b = c(12,15,21,21,22,26,31), c = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.3,0.3,0.4,0.5))
```

I am using "a" as the x-axis and "b" as the y-axis and plot a scatter plot. Is that possible that I have a secondary x-axis on the top of the panel to indicate the corresponding "c" value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was meant to be a comment rather than an answer.
We can use `sec_axis` for the purpose of adding having a secondary axis and there are several posts about it. However, in your dataset there's not a one-to-one relationship between a and c. For instance, 0.3 value in c corresponds 30, 40, 50 values in a. This makes the use of the double x axis unsatisfactory for this case. See the example below.

The issue of secondary axes using ggplot2 has been rather controversial in SO. Recent versions of ggplot2 implemented the `sec_axis` function, in which the first argument is `trans`is a transformation formula. This is particularly useful when you have a relationship between quantities e.g. Pounds and Kgs, Km and Mi, degree celsius and Kelvin, etc.

Summing up, if this your real dataset I would avoid the secondary (misleading) x axis. 
I look forward to hearing other comments on this particular problem.

```
library(ggplot2)
q = ggplot() + geom_point(data = df, aes(y = b, x = a)) 
q + scale_x_continuous("a", 
                       sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . ,  breaks = df$a, labels = df$c , name = "c"))
```

[image]